Is there another way to find the number of solutions of a polynomial equation for the integer n with smaller time complexity?
I should calculate the number of solutions for the integer n: w + 2 * x^2 + 3 * y^3 + 4 * z^4 = n and I should calculate it without arrays and with out built_in functions and the user will give me number of test cases, 0<t<1000, and 0≤n≤106. And the time limit is 5.5 seconds.
I made a loop for the test cases and an inner loop for w and an inner loop for x and for y and for z, then I checked if w + 2 * x^2 + 3 * y^3 + 4 * z^4 = n or not. If it's true, the possible ways increase by 1.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int  counter=0 , t , n;

    std::cin >> t;

    for (int k = 0; k < t; k++)
    {
        std::cin >> n;

        for (int w=0; w <= n; w++)
        {
            for (int x=0; 2*x*x<=n; x++)
            {
                for (int y=0; 3*y*y*y <= n; y++)
                {
                    for (int z=0; 4 *z*z*z*z <= n; z++)
                    {
            if (w + 2 * x * x  + 3 * y * y * y + 4 * z * z * z * z == n)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << counter << std::endl;

        counter = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}


You can calculate w from the other parameters; so drop the outermost loop and it will make your computation n times faster (i.e. up to a million times faster).

Once you fix one variable, max limit of other variables might be decreased.

Can you find a formula for w + 2 * x^2 = n? From there, you just have to iterate for y and z, removing one extra loop.

I think you should simply pre-compute the number of ways. There are only 1+22 values of z that could possibly solve it (including z=0, I assume), 1+69 values of y and 1+707 values of x.
So you can tally up the ways of using all the values of x, y and z.
Then, w is flexible. If you want n then it is formed of the sum (ways for 0)+(ways for 1)+(ways for 2)+...+(ways for n), because w can simply take the values n, n-1, ..., 0 respectively for these.
The following assumes that w, x, y, z can include the value 0 or any positive integer. It is straightforward to amend if 0 is not allowed.
You can set it to read and answer test cases yourself at the end. Make sure that the grand tallying of ways is done only once.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int nmax = 1000000;
   const int xmax = sqrt( nmax / 2.0 );
   const int ymax = pow( nmax / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0 );
   const int zmax = pow( nmax / 4.0, 0.25 );
   vector<int> xfac( 1+xmax ), yfac( 1+ymax ), zfac( 1+zmax );
   for ( int x = 0; x <= xmax; x++ ) xfac[x] = 2 * x * x;
   for ( int y = 0; y <= ymax; y++ ) yfac[y] = 3 * y * y * y;
   for ( int z = 0; z <= zmax; z++ ) zfac[z] = 4 * z * z * z * z;

   vector<int> totalxyz( 1+nmax, 0 );
   vector<int> total( 1+nmax, 0 );
   for ( int z = 0; z <= zmax; z++ )
   {
      for ( int y = 0; y <= ymax; y++ )
      {
         int yz = zfac[z] + yfac[y];
         if ( yz > nmax ) break;
         for ( int x = 0; x <= xmax; x++ )
         {
            int xyz = yz + xfac[x];
            if ( xyz > nmax ) break;
            totalxyz[xyz]++;
         }
      }
   }
   total[0] = 1;
   for ( int n = 1; n <= nmax; n++ ) total[n]=total[n-1]+totalxyz[n];

   cout << "n" << '\t' << "Ways" << '\n';
   for ( int n = 10; n <= nmax; n *= 10 ) cout << n << '\t' << total[n] << '\n';
}

Output:
n       Ways
10      9
100     63
1000    533
10000   5860
100000  67151
1000000 786501

